# Rails has_one :through with different model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-one-through

A `transaction_record` has many `workflows`, and each `workflow` has many `milestones`. One of the `milestones` is marked `current: true`, and I want to go from the `transaction_record` to the `current_milestone`:

```
class TransactionRecord < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :workflows
  has_many :milestones, through: :workflows

  # DOES NOT WORK, but what I want to do...
  has_one :current_milestone, through: :workflows, class: Milestone, source: :milestones

  # Works, but want to make an association for including
  def current_milestone
    milestones.where(current: true).first
  end
end

class Workflow < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :transaction_record
  has_many :milestones
end

class Milestone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :workflow
end
```

I can create a method that returns the desired `milestone`, but I want to make it an actual association so I can include it for DB performance.

I have a `transaction_records#index` page where I list the `transaction_records` and the `current_milestone` for each one.  That's an `n+1` unless I can figure this out.

I really want to be able to do something like:

```
@transaction_records = TransactionRecord.includes(:current_milestone)

<% @transaction_records.each do |transaction_record| %>
  <%= transaction_record.name %> - <%= transaction_record.current_milestone.name %>
<% end %>
```

## update

I can specify a direction relationship between `transaction_record` and `milestone`, and then do `transaction_record has_one :current_milestone, -> { where(current: true) }, class_name: Milestone`.  But now I'm changing my DB schema for a more efficient load query.  Not the end of the world, but not my preference if I already have an association.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't like the concept, that `transaction_record` has some kind of active_milestone without any mentioning about joining `current_workflow`.

Good solution is to think about both `workflow` and `milestone` to have an ability to be `current` and then:

```
class TransactionRecord < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :current_workflow, ....
  has_one :current_milestone, through: current_workflow, ....
end

class Workflow < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :current_milestone, condition: ....
end
```

This is far better for me, but you still need to add additional `current` flag attribute in `workflow`.

That's why better solution is rework your concept at all.
Remove `current` from milestone and add `current_milestone_id` to workflow. If it's nil, then this `workflow` has no `current_milestone`. If it contains some id, then this is your `current_workflow` and `current_milestone_id`.

Code will look pretty the same, but it will don't have ugly condition in `Workflow`